# SQL Server delete rows by inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running the following query on SQL Server:

```
delete from thisTable where id not in (
select theID from thatTable )
```

without getting the effect i expect.

In `thisTable`, there are 2 rows and their id-s are 5 & 7.

In `thatTable`, 7 doesn't appear in the `theID` field of any row - but 5 does. 
However, the above query isn't deleting the rows of `thisTable` with `id = 5`. 
In fact, the above query isn't making any changes on `thisTable` no matter what.

what am i missing?

TIA.

Comment: You're trying to delete only records which have no "match" in thatTable. Since 5 exists in both tables it will remain intact. 
What does "SELECT * from thisTable where id not in (
select theID from thatTable ) " return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `NULL`'s in the sub-query?

Try and re-write as

```
delete from thisTable 
where id not in (select theID 
                 from thatTable 
                 where theID is not null)
```

or

```
delete from thisTable 
where not exists (select * from thatTable
                  where thisTable.id = thatTable.theID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM thistable WHERE ID NOT IN(
                            SELECT thistable.ID
                            FROM thistable INNER JOIN thatTable
                            ON thistable.id = thatTable.id)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a4f63/9)

Comment: join is too costly for this much. jarlh's query worked. thx for the effort.